# CryptographicException Bad Key when trying to load public key into RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, rsa, blazor

I'm not sure how this issue is happening, the key that I'm attempting to pass to the CSP was originally a Base64Encoded string which I've tried passing in using ImportSubjectInfoKey() as well. Each time when debugging I have exported the parameters and I am able to get my public key back as a Base64 string so as far as I know it's a valid key. However once it hits the VerifyData method it breaks with a Bad Key exception. While debugging, I did notice that rsa1.CspKeyContainerInfo was mentioning an error "Exportable: {key does not exist}". Is this where my issue is coming from? I've included the public key below as an XML string if anyone can see an issue.

```
    private static bool VerifyData(string paymentToken, string signature)
    {

        var rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        string publicKey = @"
            <RSAKeyValue><Modulus>zIU140G9rFe6ouNFuhCxIj3Ps3ELUV9w4XTnDsti8kcSTXMf0z6LMNVIqXaZYFbSYXAZRmuM3XNmoSWmMZzPBMl2/C7uC0wyNdrYdPw0uzU2wfr8MQbnvW0yQgQ/cSHNDUZR+n/s2ipXTdNmbRd4z+k+qXxw00xMDmiJu5iMHyYo24x284lTZ3+4dgL4xFlrtjgcb/NGHBpVPQTCbBfEQcmylCwzbTUdBJlAo5ezpziOJ6CNf9FDS1hvRKRvNl7Hx8To6vQZJTwdCT5RWDC2JYL0oSdPV+SZmlfHQQe33p81MiRl4cjp5AwMVKyAosDihGT810WFYhK431EIB/NR/w==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
        
        rsa1.FromXmlString(publicKey);

        // Converts back to my original Base64 encoded public key so it seems valid.
        var x = rsa1.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
        var a = Convert.ToBase64String(x);

        RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter rsaDeformatter = new(rsa1);
        rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

        var paymentTokenAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paymentToken);
        var signatureAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

        bool verified = false;
        try
        {
            if (rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(paymentTokenAsBytes, signatureAsBytes))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The signature is valid.");
                verified = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The signature is not valid.");
                verified = false;
            }
        } catch(CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"What is going on!! {ex} ");
        }
        return verified;
```

Error:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Bad Key.
at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateHashHandle(SafeProvHandle hProv, Byte[] hash, Int32 
calgHash)
at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.VerifySign(SafeProvHandle hProv, SafeKeyHandle hKey, Int32 
calgKey, Int32 calgHash, Byte[] hash, Byte[] signature)
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(Byte[] hash, Byte[] signature, 
HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter.VerifySignature(Byte[] rgbHash, Byte[] 
rgbSignature)
at Go.Server.Controllers.CitizenWebhook.VerifyData(String paymentToken, String signature) in 
C:\Users\Dylan\source\repos\GO5050PLATFORM\Go\Server\Controllers\Webhooks\CitizenWebhook.cs:line 108
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code fails because [`VerifySignature()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1signaturedeformatter.verifysignature?view=net-5.0) doesn't expect the raw data but the *hashed* data, see also [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1signaturedeformatter.verifysignature?view=net-5.0#examples) from the documentation.

With the following change:

```
var paymentTokenAsBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(paymentToken));
```

the verification is successful.

---

If the key is available in X.509/SPKI format (DER encoded), it can alternatively be imported with [`ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-5.0). For verification, the methods [`VerifyData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifydata?view=net-5.0) (hashes the data implicitly) and [`VerifyHash()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifyhash?view=net-5.0) (expects the already hashed data) can be used alternatively.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for a while now you've really helped me out! Can't believe I was so close I rewrote my key part soo many times because I thought it was that. Thanks again :)